# How do I compare 2-d tensor with 1-d tensor in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, array-broadcasting

Example of what I want to compare these two:

```
torch.tensor([[1,2],[1,2],[1,3]]) == torch.tensor([1,2])
```

I want this output:

```
[True, True, False]
```

But instead the broadcasting gets me:

```
tensor([[ True,  True],
        [ True,  True],
        [ True, False]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator is always element-wise, even when broadcasting. You can get your desired result by aggregating with `all` along the last axis.

```py
a = torch.tensor([[1,2],[1,2],[1,3]]) 
b = torch.tensor([1,2])

output1 = a == b
>tensor([[ True,  True],
         [ True,  True],
         [ True, False]])

output2 = output1.all(-1)
>tensor([ True,  True, False])
```

Also if it matters for your use case, you can use reductions like `all` with `keepdim=True` to retain the number of dims.

```py
output2 = output1.all(-1) # shape (3,)
>tensor([ True,  True, False])

output2 = output1.all(-1, keepdim=True) # shape (3, 1)
>tensor([[ True],
         [ True],
         [False]])
```